How to validate all dropped components using ngx-drag-drop with Angular forms?
I am using the ngx-drag-drop library in my Angular project. Each dropped item represents a component, and each component can have multiple child components, all of which are using Angular reactive forms.
I need to check the validity of all the dropped components (and their child components) after a drop event, so I can ensure the forms in all components are valid.
How can I trigger validation checks for all components after a drop event? Is there a way to gather and check the form validity of all dropped components dynamically?
Here’s a simplified version of what I’m working with:
Each dropped component contains a form.

Some components have child components, which also contain forms.
I want to ensure that all dropped forms are valid before allowing further action.
What would be the best approach to achieve this validation across multiple dropped components?

I wrote this function but it's going to check validity of a single component:
    public hasValidator(control: string): void {
        if (this.form.controls[control].hasValidator(Validators.required)) {
            let valid = this.form.controls[control].valid;
            this.isValid$ = this.isValid$ && valid;
        }
    }


The cleanest solution might be to have each component implement the ControlValueAccessor interface. This allows each component to function as a FormGroup, encapsulating the state of its child forms. When you drag a form into another component, you can easily add it as a form control and validate the entire structure using Angular's Forms API.

@BizzyBob Thanks for the suggestion! Implementing ControlValueAccessor seems like a great idea. I’m wondering, though, how would this work with components with multiple nested child forms? Specifically:
How would I register each dropped component (and its child components) as part of a parent FormGroup dynamically after the drop event?
How would I ensure that the child forms are validated correctly along with their parent form?
Are there any gotchas or things I should know when implementing ControlValueAccessor for dynamic, nested components in a drag-and-drop scenario?
